# SaveGame variables changing by themselves between levels

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-savegame

I have a SaveGame subclass that I've made to hold my game data so that it persists between levels. I create the object and set a couple variables in the HUD of the first world and then save it to the slot.

[image]

At the end, the print string node outputs False, as expected. I then load directly into the next level and load the savegame from the same slot.

[image]

But now, the Branch at the end here is returning true. How? Everything else persists properly, but this one value returns true when it was just false a second ago. I can confirm that this happens coming from two different levels, where one is set in the level blueprint and one is set in the HUD blueprint.

What is wrong? Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you opened a bug report? Your blueprint looks good to me.

Comment: Are you saving game using Blueprint or C++? Did you find out what the problem is?